# Правописание "не" с наречиями

Tags: грамотная-речь, частица-не

Филологи, можете, пожалуйста, проверить мой текст и объяснить ошибки?

> Иван нескладно взмахнул руками и неожиданно сорвался вниз. Когда чувство страха прошло, он понял, что упал на песок, не глубоко и не ушибся. Ему не больно, но досадно и не понятно, как отсюда выбраться...
>   Иван невесело размышляет о своём приключении, но уже карабкается вверх, слишком спешит, срывается и потому продвигается не быстро, а медленно. Наконец, он ухватился за ветку и немедленно оказался на прежнем месте.

Где здесь предикативные наречия? Почему именно так, а не по-другому пишутся в данном тексте не с наречиями? Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в этой теме, просто завтра зачёт, и не хотелось бы завалить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Излагаю свое понимание, но я не филолог, так что на веру не принимать.

*Нескладно* пишется слитно, так как без *не* не употребляется.

*Неожиданно* пишется слитно, так как без *не* не употребляется.

*Упал на песок, не глубоко* — смысл туманный. Упал НА песок, значит не погрузился совсем, ни глубоко, ни мелко.  Как вариант: погрузился в песок не_глубоко и не ушибся. Думаю, возможно и слитное, и раздельное написание (если автор подразумевает отрицание).

*Ему не больно* — раздельно.

> Различается написание не с безлично-предикативными словами на о и созвучными с ними краткими прилагательными и наречиями (http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.57)

*Ему ... не понятно, как отсюда выбраться* — раздельно, ему не было понятно, здесь отрицание. Однако если поставить запятую перед *и*, то получим безличное предложение "И непонятно, как отсюда выбраться".

*Невесело* — грустно, нет отрицания.

*Не быстро, а медленно* — раздельно, явное противопоставление.

*Немедленно оказался* — слитно, быстро оказался , нет отрицания.

Comment: _Нескладно пишется слитно, так как без не не употребляется._  **Скла́дно**: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/244830/Складно. _Как складно сидит на них обмундирование!_  _Фигурка (…) смотрелась очень складно._

Comment: @Римма Михайлова, все равно пишется слитно. А *складно* — редкое слово. Если у Вас есть другое объяснение — you are wellcome.

Answer (score 3):

Иван **нескладно** взмахнул руками и **неожиданно** сорвался вниз. Когда чувство страха прошло, он понял, что упал на песок, **не глубоко** и не ушибся. Ему **не больно, но досадно и непонятно,** как отсюда выбраться...

Иван **невесело** размышляет о своём приключении, но уже карабкается вверх, слишком спешит, срывается и потому продвигается **не быстро, а медленно.** Наконец, он ухватился за ветку и **немедленно** оказался на прежнем месте.

1) **Обстоятельственные наречия**

Утверждение, возможна замена синонимом без НЕ: **нескладно** (неуклюже), **неожиданно** (внезапно), **невесело** (грустно), **немедленно** (сейчас же).

**Не быстро, а медленно** — противопоставление.

Авторский выбор по смыслу: **не глубоко** (на среднюю глубину) и **неглубоко** (мелко).

2) **Предикативные наречия**

**Не больно**, но досадно и **непонятно**

**Не больно** — только раздельно, **непонятно** (в середине предложения чаще слитно)

**О предикативных наречиях (грамматическая справка):**

Слово категории состояния  (безлично-предикативное слово) – это часть речи, обозначающая состояние живых существ, природы, иногда с модальной окраской или выражением оценки. Модальность слов категории состояния связана или  с объективной оценкой реальности как  действительное, возможное или желаемое, или    с субъективным отношением говорящего к содержанию речи и выражением его чувств.

Слова категории состояния употребляются в функции **сказуемого** в безличном предложении. В роли слов категории состояния могут использоваться различные части речи, а именно:  а) **безлично-предикативные наречия на О**;  б) существительные (а также соотнесенные с ними слова);  в) краткие предикативные прилагательные. Мне грустно. На улице темно. Сегодня прохладно. Жаль отца.

**Предикативные наречия на О могут писаться с НЕ слитно или раздельно:**

**1) Выбор слитного или раздельного написания НЕ по смыслу**

НЕ с предикативными наречиями на О обычно может писаться как слитно, так и раздельно, при этом орфограмма имеет смысловое решение, которое во многих случаях является авторским:

Слитное написание НЕ при утверждении противоположного признака, возможна  замена синонимом без НЕ: непросто (трудно) говорить об этом, непростительно  обманывать друга, нехорошо  оставлять людей в беде, неизвестно, что будет дальше.

Раздельное написание НЕ при отрицании: Обычно логическое выделение в начале предложения:  Не просто (не является простым) сделать первый шаг.   Не трудно угадать, что будет дальше.

2) **Только раздельное написание предикативных наречий на О**
В некоторых случаях слова на  О не соединяются  с приставкой НЕ  для образования нового слова и поэтому всегда пишутся с НЕ  всегда раздельно: не стыдно, не совестно, не страшно, не надо, не надобно.

3) Предикативные наречия могут иметь при себе слова, **усиливающие утверждении или отрицание:**

Совершенно непонятно,  для чего это делается (усиление утверждения). Куда несет нас неведомая сила – никому не известно (усиление отрицания)

4) При выборе формы написания НЕ со  словами на О следует различать **три варианта**: обстоятельственные наречия, предикативные наречия  и краткие прилагательные.

Наступить незаметно – обстоятельственное  наречие, чаще слитное написание.

Незаметно и не заметно – предикативные наречия, смысловое решение орфограммы: Здоровье его недурно, также незаметно, чтобы он скучал.  Не заметно, чтобы он раскаялся (логическое выделение отрицания)

Гнездо незаметно в траве.  Краткое прилагательное (обычно слитно)

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о двух разных решениях, как выбрать верное).**

Материал о предикативных наречиях можно посмотреть у Розенталя http://www.rosental-book.ru/ortho_xvii.html#sect71.5  (пункт 5). В частности там говорится о логическом выделении отрицательных конструкций.

Обратим внимание, что в ответах на форуме  вам были предложены разные формы написания:  ***непонятно и не понятно.***

По Розенталю, в начале предложения можно встретить обе формы: (1) **не понятно** (нельзя понять), как решать эту задачу (отрицание); (2) **непонятно** (сложно понять), как решать эту задачу (утверждение).

Смысл примерно одинаков, поэтому важна структура предложения.

В начале предложения возможны оба варианта, но при этом  **отрицательную форму мы логически выделяем.**

А вот в середине предложения ударения уже расставлены: Ему **не бОльно**, но **досАдно** и непонятно, как отсюда **вЫбраться**. Ударением выделены ключевые слова в обороте НЕ...НО, поэтому написание предикативного наречия должно быть слитным: ***непонятно***.

Comment: "Неуклюже" - это синоним без *не*?

Comment: Это синоним с НЕ, но это однозначно приставка НЕ, так как слово без НЕ не существует. А зачем вообще в правиле указан синоним без НЕ? Я думаю это для того, чтобы мы были уверены в утвердительном характере слова.  Вы же не сомневаетесь, что у слова "неуклюже" именно утвердительный характер?